# What does happen with kernel level threads when process ends?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, pthreads

If we have a process with kernel level threads running, and that process ends what does exactly happen with those threads?

I suppose they end too, but what are exact steps?

Comment: You seem to have it backwards.  A process has not yet ended while any of its threads is still running, so when a process does end there aren't any more threads to worry about, by definition.  There is no difference between kernel-level and user-level threads in this general regard.  If you have a more specific question, preferably one supported by example code, then you could consider editing the question to clarify what you actually want to know.

Comment: I don't have code example, this was question from operating systems exam and I was confused a bit. @JohnBollinger

Comment: Presumably, then, the answer is in your class notes and / or textbook, and the terminology used on the exam will match up with those.  As it stands, the question is unclear, but it seems likely to be too broad for SO.  If you yourself cannot at least *construct* example code that demonstrates the scenario you want to know about, then I cannot imagine how you expect us to divine what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose they end too, but what are exact steps?

The exact steps are: they simply evaporate into nothing.

More precisely, when the process executes `exit` (or `exit_group` on Linux) system call, the OS deschedules any running threads, whatever instruction they are currently on, and then destroys all kernel resources associated with them (memory mappings, file descriptors, etc.).

It's as if the kernel plucks them out of existence. One moment they are executing on CPU or waiting to be scheduled, and the next moment they simply do not exist.

Comment: Yes, and I can add that 'deschedules any running threads' requires that any cores running other threads of the process need to be hardware-interrupted to force entry into the kernel,  The OS interprocessor comms driver can do this, user code cannot.